# Windows not returning any IPv6 address in DNS lookup

Tags: windows, networking, dns, java, ipv6

My DNS contains two records for ServerA:

- an A record with its IPv4 address: 10.25.46.130
- an AAAA record with its IPv6 address: fda8:6c3:ce53:a890::55

I am not able to get my *SimpleClient.java* program *(source at the end of this post)* on a Windows server to list the IPv6 address of *ServerA* using `InetAddress.getAllByName()`, even when configuring the JVM with `-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true`.

The same test running on an IPv6 enabled Linux server is successful.

Configuration details:

- Windows: Server 2019 Standard (10.0.17763)
- Java: OpenJDK 11.0.5+

The output of `ipconfig` on the Windows server shows that IPv6 seems enabled:

```
> ipconfig
Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.25.0.214
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : X.X.X.X
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : X.X.X.X

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : fr.company.com
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fda8:6c3:ce53:a890::3
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : X.X.X.X::X
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : X.X.X.X::X
```

The `nslookup` output from the Windows server is the expected one:

```
> nslookup ServerA
Server:  dns.fr.company.com
Address:  X.X.X.X

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    ServerA.fr.company.com
Addresses:  fda8:6c3:ce53:a890::55
          10.25.46.130
```

I am able to successfully run `ping -6 ServerA` from the Windows server:

```
> ping -6 ServerA
Pinging ServerA.fr.company.com [fda8:6c3:ce53:a890::55] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fda8:6c3:ce53:a890::55: time<1ms
Reply from fda8:6c3:ce53:a890::55: time<1ms
```

Below is the **expected output** running from an IPv6 enabled Linux server:

```
# IPv4 (default)
$ java SimpleClient.java ServerA 12345
preferIPv6Addresses: null
InetAddress.getByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130
InetAddress.getAllByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130
ServerA/fda8:6c3:ce53:a890:0:0:0:55

# IPv6
$ java -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true SimpleClient.java ServerA 12345
preferIPv6Addresses: true
InetAddress.getByName()
ServerA/fda8:6c3:ce53:a890:0:0:0:55
InetAddress.getAllByName()
ServerA/fda8:6c3:ce53:a890:0:0:0:55
ServerA/10.25.46.130
```

The same test failing on the Windows server:

```
# IPv4 (default)
> java SimpleClient.java ServerA 12345
preferIPv6Addresses: null
InetAddress.getByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130
InetAddress.getAllByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130

# IPv6
> java -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true SimpleClient.java ServerA 12345
preferIPv6Addresses: true
InetAddress.getByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130
InetAddress.getAllByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130
```

On the Windows server, the call to `InetAddress.getAllByName()` is only returning a single IPv4 address and not both an IPv4 and IPv6 address like as expected on the Linux IPv6 enabled server.

I can reproduce the same behavior on a Linux server with IPv6 disabled (grub and kernel settings):

```
# IPv4 (default)
$ java SimpleClient.java ServerA 12345
preferIPv6Addresses: null
InetAddress.getByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130
InetAddress.getAllByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130

# IPv6
$ java -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true SimpleClient.java ServerA 12345
preferIPv6Addresses: true
InetAddress.getByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130
InetAddress.getAllByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130
```

From these tests, I conclude that something is wrong somewhere on the IPv6 configuration of the Windows server but I don't know what.

Some notes and stuff I tried:

- Manually adding the IPv6 address of *ServerA* in *C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts* results in the program to list the IPv6 address, but only this one.
- I did not find a `DisabledComponents` key in the registy for the path `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters`

Below is the code for *SampleClient.java*:

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SimpleClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 2) return;
        String hostname = args[0];
        System.out.println("preferIPv6Addresses: " + System.getProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses"));
        try {
          System.out.println("InetAddress.getByName()");
          System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName(hostname));
          InetAddress[] addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName(hostname);
          System.out.println("InetAddress.getAllByName()");
          for (InetAddress address : addresses) {
            System.out.println(address);
          }
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println("Server not found: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port)) {
            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println("Server not found: " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("I/O error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody hint at something that might be wrong on the Windows server configuration?

Thank you.

**EDIT1:**

As mentioned in the comments, I also reproduced the issue with Python using `socket.getaddrinfo()`:

- Windows server (no *AF_INET6*)

```
>>> socket.getaddrinfo("serverA", 12345)
[(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, 0, 0, '', ('10.25.46.130', 12345))]
```

- Linux server (both *AF_INET6* and *AF_INET*)

```
>>> socket.getaddrinfo("serverA", 12345)
[(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '', ('10.25.46.130', 12345)),
 (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM: 2>, 17, '', ('10.25.46.130', 12345)),
 (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_RAW: 3>, 0, '', ('10.25.46.130', 12345)),
 (<AddressFamily.AF_INET6: 10>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '', ('fda8:6c3:ce53:a890::55', 12345, 0, 0)),
 (<AddressFamily.AF_INET6: 10>, <SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM: 2>, 17, '', ('fda8:6c3:ce53:a890::55', 12345, 0, 0)),
 (<AddressFamily.AF_INET6: 10>, <SocketKind.SOCK_RAW: 3>, 0, '', ('fda8:6c3:ce53:a890::55', 12345, 0, 0))]
```

Comment: For reference, I posted the same question as well on StackOverflow since I don't know if the issue comes from the JVM or from the Windows configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72060475/java-inetaddress-getallbyname-not-returning-ipv6-address-on-windows-even-with

Comment: Can you reproduce this with other Windows programs that use the OS-provided name lookup functions (e.g. Python's `socket.getaddrinfo`)?

Comment: I reproduced with Python on Windows:
`>>> socket.getaddrinfo("serverA", 12345)
[(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, 0, 0, '', ('10.25.46.130', 12345))]`

The same call on my Linux VM returns way more entries with both AF_INET and AF_INET6 AddressFamily.

Comment: Sounds like an OS configuration issue then – not a Java issue. Do you have other Windows systems to test on? In particular, does it somehow depend on whether the same interface has both IPv4 and IPv6 (in your example they're somehow separate)...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any other Windows server to test on, my company's internal network is IPv4 only and machines are configured accordingly...

Comment: After your comment, I disabled all the extra network interfaces and kept only the first one that I reconfigured to do both IPv4 and IPv6 (our IT provisioned two interfaces, one dedicated to each IP stack).
Having a single interface with both IPv4 and IPV6 I am now getting the expected output of my test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came from @user1686 in the comments, pointing out that IPv4 and IPv6 were separated on different interfaces.

It seems that our IT provisioned the Windows server with two interfaces, one dedicated for each IP stack:

- *Ethernet* (IPv4)
- *Ethernet4* (IPv6)

I disabled all extra interfaces on the Windows server and kept only the “*Ethernet*” one:

[image: Disabling interfaces in Network manager]

I manually re-configured the IPv6 stack on “*Ethernet*” by copy pasting the settings and properties from “*Ethernet 4*”:

[image: Enabling IPv6 on IPv6 only interface]

The resulting *ipconfig* shows a single interface with both IPv4 and IPv6:

```
> ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fda8:6c3:ce53:a890::3
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8d10:5083:9a0:9ab8%16
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.25.0.214
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : Z.Z.Z.Z
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : Y:Y:Y:Y::T
                                       X.X.X.X
```

After this reconfiguration, the test is behaving correctly and lists both the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses for serverA:

```
# IPv4
> C:\jdk11.0.8\bin\java SimpleClient.java serverA 12345
preferIPv6Addresses: null
InetAddress.getByName()
serverA/10.25.46.130
InetAddress.getAllByName()
serverA/10.25.46.130
serverA/fda8:6c3:ce53:a890:0:0:0:55

# IPv6
> C:\jdk11.0.8\bin\java -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true SimpleClient.java serverA 12345
preferIPv6Addresses: true
InetAddress.getByName()
serverA/fda8:6c3:ce53:a890:0:0:0:55
InetAddress.getAllByName()
serverA/fda8:6c3:ce53:a890:0:0:0:55
serverA/10.25.46.130
```

So it definitely seems that trying to segregate IP stacks on different interfaces is **not** a good idea.